# How to force a method to throw an Exception in jUnit testing?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, testing, junit

Actually this is for code coverage and I'm having a hard time, covering to `catch` statements.
Any ideas?

for example:

I want my `selectSomethingBySomething()` method (which selects from db) to throw an `SQLException` which is pretty hard on a test method without actually touching the actual source code. Given also the constraint that what I can only control is the parameters for the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You need a mocking framework like Mockito. Check out the easy-to-read refcard here: http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/mockito

Comment: You should be making a mock of your database connection object, not actually sending SQL to the database. You're testing your code, not the database. If you don't know about mocking, a quick google search should find plenty of good introductions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to first mock the class containing `selectSomethingBySomething()` and then record this behavior. In [mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito) you'll say:

```
SomeDao someDaoMock = mock(SomeDao.class);

willThrow(new SQLException())).given(someDaoMock).selectSomethingBySomething();
```

Then inject `someDaoMock` into your class under test and when it calls `someDaoMock.selectSomethingBySomething()` it'll throw previously chosen exception.

Answer (score 1):

Using EasyMock you can mock an Class and the method calls of that particular Class.

For example:

If DoSomethingDAO is the ClassName,

Mock the class like DoSomethingDAO mockDAO

```
EasyMock.createMock(DoSomethingDAO.class);
```

now that you have to mock all the calls that are being made from this mockDAO.

if the method returns a value we need to mock the call like below.

```
EasyMock.expect(mockDAO.selectSomethingBySomething()).andReturn(EasyMock.anyObject());
```

If the method throws an exception below is the method call

```
EasyMock.expect(mockDAO.selectSomethingBySomething()).andThrow(new (typeofExecption));
```

for void methods

```
mockDAO.selectSomethingBySomething();
EasyMock.expectLastCall().atleastOnce();
```

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of ways do it, but my advice is don't aim for 100% code coverage. It simply isn't worth it. You're making life difficult for yourself for negligible benefit.

However, if you really want to test it, probably the best way is to alter your code to make it more testable. Make your data-access class implement an interface, then use a mocking framework (such as JMock) to mock it out and throw a SQLException. (You can mock concrete classes but that is frowned on.)

Comment: Really late (after 10+ years). In my opinon, a developer NEED to do for 100%. Every piece of code need a test.

Comment: If we had infinite time, I would agree, but our time is limited and we should spend it where it counts most and not waste it. Some code is much more important than other code. It's better to test (and improve) the important code than spend time testing code of low-importance and the handling of, say, an `IOException` that cannot actually occur because we already checked for the condition beforehand etc. You have to look at the pros and cons of 100% test coverage. Not just the pros.

Comment: The issue is there: you see tests as waste time. No, tests are part of sw development. Like powering on the pc. When my PM ask me forecast of time development, in my time there are also the test.

Comment: No, you have misunderstood my point. It's not that I see tests as a waste of time. It's that I see *some* tests as a waste of *limited time*. It's about investment vs reward, given the reality that if we spend time in one place, we do not spend it in another place.

Answer (score -1):

You actually do not need an additional Framework to do the Trick.
Here is how:

```
    Exception hasToBeThrown = null;
    try {
                 methodThatShouldThrow();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertTrue(e.getMessage().startsWith("if you want to...")); // JUnit will miss this, if not thrown, so we need more
        hasToBeThrown = e;
    }
    assertNotNull(hasToBeThrown); // but this will do
```